# Vertical spacing within float

Tags: tables, spacing, floats

I have a `table` in which I want to include two `tabular` elements one below the other (and justified right).

Right now I have this code, that displays exactly what I want.. I would like to add some spacing between the two tabulars.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
     1 & 2 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \\ \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
     3 & 4 \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\caption{two tables}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I tried to put `vspace` between the two tabulars, but it adds me the vertical space between the second one and the caption

Comment: [welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/PiJ21)

Comment: thanks! I searched the site before asking, most of the questions deal with spacing within the tabular environment (but referred as table, that makes my research though)

Comment: You already have an answer how to do it. To see why your answer doesn't work, notice that `\hline` only works _inside the `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\raggedleft
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
     1 & 2 \\
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace*{1em}
  \hrule
  \vspace*{1em}

  \hfill    
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
     3 & 4 \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\caption{two tables}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\vspace*` does the job, thanks! but now I can't move the second table to the right with `\hfill`

Comment: ok. it seems that the basic thing I was missing is that double return to separate elements works also in floats. I was placing `\hline` right after `\vspace`

Comment: `\par` is an alternative you can use instead of the two line breaks.

Comment: Why not saying `\raggedleft` inside `table` so that you don't need to push the objects to the right margin manually? This won't act on the caption, which is typeset with its own method.

Comment: I did try putting the `tabular`s into a `raggedleft` environment, which didn't work, so I simply kept OP's `\hfill` approach. But `\raggedleft` does work indeed.

Comment: The environment form is `\begin{flushright}` If you use raggedleft as an environment and don't include a blank line before `\end` the paragraph settings end before the paragraph ends so they do nothing.